# Pegar informação específica em string

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta que recolhe de uma string somente os campos ID e o nome. Porém não sei fazer isso em php segue abaixo a string.

```
<s:Label x="10" y="10" text="NOME"/>
                <s:TextInput id="NOME" x="10" y="21" width="290" tabIndex="1"/>
                <s:Label x="10" y="50" text="TELEFONE"/>
                <s:Label x="120" y="50" text="RAMAL"/>
                <s:TextInput id="RAMAL" x="120" y="61" width="102" tabIndex="5"/>
                <s:Label x="365" y="50" text="LOGIN"/>
                <s:TextInput id="LOGIN1" x="365" y="61" width="102" tabIndex="7"/>
                <s:TextInput id="TELEFONE" x="10" y="61" width="102" tabIndex="4"/>
                <s:Label x="308" y="11" text="EMAIL"/>
                <s:TextInput id="EMAIL" x="308" y="22" width="290" tabIndex="2"/>
                <s:Label x="605" y="10" text="MATRICULA"/>
                <s:TextInput id="MATRICULA" x="606" y="22" width="144"  tabIndex="3"/>
                <s:Label x="627" y="91" text="NASCIMENTO"/>
                <s:TextInput id="NASCIMENTO" x="627" y="103" width="121" tabIndex="14"/>
```

Notem que em cada objeto exceto o label existe um ID preciso pegar o conteúdo dentro das aspas simples exemplo: id="NOME"  quero pegar o NOME

Como fazer isso? Lembrando que essa string pode ser gigantesca

Comment: Isso tudo é uma string, com quebra de linha e tudo?

Comment: Sim, e só preciso pegar os conteúdos dos IDs

Comment: Creio que um `preg_match_all('/id="(.+?)"/', $str, $matches); var_dump($matches[1]);` resolve. A variável `$str` é onde está armazenada a string.

Comment: Rapaz vc é um gênio é isso mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar `preg_match_all` com uma expressão regular para pegar tudo que estiver entre as aspas duplas de `id=""`:

```
preg_match_all('/id="(.+?)"/', $str, $matches);
```

A expressão `/id="(.+?)"/` irá buscar tudo que tiver `id=""` e a parte `(.+?)` separa no grupo 1 tudo que estiver entre as aspas. O resultado é uma array com dois índices (`[0]` e `[1]`) onde no índice `[0]` está o padrão completo (`id="alguma coisa"`) e no índice `[1]` o que está entre as aspas.

Logo, interessa a você apenas o índice `[1]`:

```
$matches[1]
```

[Veja no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/6gxAGg)

Answer (score 2):

Essa string me parece ser um recorte de um XML, porém está mal formada (faltam algumas partes).

Você pode ler essa string com o [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
<?php

$xml = <<<'XML'
<root xmlns:s="http://some-address.com">
    <s:Label x="10" y="10" text="NOME"/>
    <s:TextInput id="NOME" x="10" y="21" width="290" tabIndex="1"/>
    <s:Label x="10" y="50" text="TELEFONE"/>
    <s:Label x="120" y="50" text="RAMAL"/>
    <s:TextInput id="RAMAL" x="120" y="61" width="102" tabIndex="5"/>
    <s:Label x="365" y="50" text="LOGIN"/>
    <s:TextInput id="LOGIN1" x="365" y="61" width="102" tabIndex="7"/>
    <s:TextInput id="TELEFONE" x="10" y="61" width="102" tabIndex="4"/>
    <s:Label x="308" y="11" text="EMAIL"/>
    <s:TextInput id="EMAIL" x="308" y="22" width="290" tabIndex="2"/>
    <s:Label x="605" y="10" text="MATRICULA"/>
    <s:TextInput id="MATRICULA" x="606" y="22" width="144"  tabIndex="3"/>
    <s:Label x="627" y="91" text="NASCIMENTO"/>
    <s:TextInput id="NASCIMENTO" x="627" y="103" width="121" tabIndex="14"/>
</root>
XML;

$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xpathTextInput = $simpleXML->xpath('s:TextInput');

foreach($xpathTextInput as $input) {
    echo $input['id'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Resultado:

```
NOME
RAMAL
LOGIN1
TELEFONE
EMAIL
MATRICULA
NASCIMENTO
```

Alterei um pouco para tornar o XML válido (é preciso de uma tag raiz e também declarar o *namespace*). [Veja funcionando aqui](https://3v4l.org/EB3ah).

Veja algumas referencias aqui:

- [Exemplo básico com SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)
- [Exemplos com XPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Sintaxe do XML](https://hugoribeiro.com.br/Curso_HTML/xml/c03.htm)